# JAXWS-maven-plugin generates xsi:type and xmlns:xsi in generated xml

Tags: jaxb2, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am facing an issue with JAXWS generated XML containing unwanted xsi:type and xsi:schema tags.I read other threads but none has helped me so far.
In my case , i have only WSDL and XSDs and i am using jaxws-maven-plugin to generate code from WSDL(which includes XSDs)

1) jaxws-maven-plugin configuration:

```
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingFiles><bindingFile>Booking_normalized/Booking_1.0.1.0.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                            <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>Booking_normalized/Booking_1.0.1.0.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <target>2.1</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

2) XSD(imported inside WSDL):

```
    <xs:complexType name="ScheduleQueryType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Describes a Schedule</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="start" type="ScheduleQueryTypestart"/>
            <xs:element name="end" type="ScheduleQueryTypeend"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ScheduleQueryTypestart">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    The start element contains the origin locationCode and departure dateTime
                </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="DateTimeLocationType">
                <xs:attribute name="windowBefore" type="xs:duration" use="optional">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">A period of time that can be applied to another time resulting in an earlier range of time.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="windowAfter" type="xs:duration" use="optional">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">A period of time that can be applied to another time resulting in a later range of time.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ScheduleQueryTypeend">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    The end element contains the destination locationCode and arrival dateTime.
                </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="DateTimeLocationType">
                <xs:attribute name="windowBefore" type="xs:duration" use="optional">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">A period of time that can be applied to another time resulting in an earlier range of time.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="windowAfter" type="xs:duration" use="optional">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">A period of time that can be applied to another time resulting in a later range of time.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DateTimeLocationType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Describes DateTime and Location</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="locationCode" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Code used to identify a location</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="ota:StringLength1to16">
                            <xs:attribute name="type" type="ota:AlphaNumericStringLength1to8" use="optional">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Type of location code</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="dateTime" type="ota:DateOrDateTimeType">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Date and optional time</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="locationName" type="ota:StringLength1to64" use="optional">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Name of the location</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
```

3) Generated XML:

```
<ns5:Schedule>
            <ns5:Segment TID="SEG_1" Inventory="FRR">
                <ns2:start xsi:type="ns2:ScheduleQueryTypestart" dateTime="2015-05-06" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ns2:locationCode type="NLS">FRPLY</ns2:locationCode>
                </ns2:start>
                <ns2:end xsi:type="ns2:ScheduleQueryTypeend" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ns2:locationCode type="NLS">FRLPD</ns2:locationCode>
                </ns2:end>
                <ns2:serviceProvider Code="SNF"/>
                <ns2:identifier>6609</ns2:identifier>
            </ns5:Segment>
        </ns5:Schedule>
```

As you can see above that in Generated XML, the tags start and end contains xmlns:xsi and xsi:type tag. I want to get rid of them. Any suggestions?

Please note that other items in the generated XML are OK(they dont contain xsi prefix).

Here this is not simply a type conversion ( which would have been solved using  javaType binding. It's more of using a complex type. Could it really be a plugin problem or there is something wrong with my XSD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the start and end type were used in more than one types. Sorry that i could not mentioned the whole XSD here, it would have been found way earlier. [We also noted that the builder we were using had few issues]. So JAXB had to put the type attribute to make distinction.

Problem found and resolved.

Thanks to all.